# Transparent control or user control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, transparency, parent-child

I am trying to make a transparent control with child controls that are visible and opaque.

I have added a panel control to the main form via code in the form load event. In this I am adding five buttons as child controls like: panel.controls.add(). To all of these, I have set backcolor=color.transparent.

When I run this program, the button background shows the background of the next button in the panel. If I open a child form, then I can see labels on the child form as the background of the panel.

I want to make container panel control completely transparent, so I can see the main form through it. How can this be achieved?

1. [image: When the form loads]  When the form loads, you can see neighbor buttons behind the actual buttons
2. [image: After opening a child form: The form has a label "Perform Check" on it, which can be seen here:]   "Perform Check" is a label on a child form which I opened right before taking this picture.
3. [image: After opening another child form which has a button "Check cases and combinations" which can be seen in the background.] : "Check Cases and Combinations" is a button on a child form which I opened right before I took this picture.

How can I make it truly transparent? Why doesn't the background of the panel control refresh with the main form background? The panel sort of "keeps" whatever happens on the main form and shows it as a background.

Comment: You need to improve your question.

Comment: I don't know how else to put it. Maybe these images will help?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you are trying to achieve? The images do not help much unfortunatelly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there some issues with setting controls that are transparent and on top of other controls in the main form. They take the background of the container form, whether or not there is any control in between. I used WPF form instead of the panel and it worked perfectly.